# Is there a reason why \epigraph{}{} is causing the paragraph after it to have all its spaces removed and be in italics?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, formatting

Currently, using pdfLaTeX, the following code:

```
\epigraph{"[Boleslaus] meanwhile, because of his severity and the horrors of his crimes, … though he was awarded the crown royal, shall not be placed among the Polish kings and princes.}{Wielkopolska Chronicle}
```

It seems likely that Boleslaus was, if not the leader, at least instrumental in the Pagan Reaction, a mutiny of the nobility in the 1030s in an attempt to ward off Christianity.

gives me this:

[image]

The text is overall in two columns, which explains why some of the text which runs off the page is invisible.

If I insert a blank line between the end of the epigram and the start of the text like so:

```
\epigraph{"[Boleslaus] meanwhile, because of his severity and the horrors of his crimes, … though he was awarded the crown royal, shall not be placed among the Polish kings and princes.}{Wielkopolska Chronicle}

It seems likely that Boleslaus was, if not the leader, at least instrumental in the Pagan Reaction, a mutiny of the nobility in the 1030s in an attempt to ward off Christianity.
```

the reaction i get is[image]

but the extra blank space causes orphans.

Thanks in advance!

edit: a minimal code-error:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

No sources from the time explicitly indicate his existence – indications of him in the earliest primary sources are limited to a mention of Boleslaus II (r. 1058-1076) with an extra ‘I’ in the Tyniec Sacramentary\footnote{A sacramentarium is a Catholic liturgical book akin to a Missal, but lacking all the parts not said by the priest.}, written about thirty years after the Forgotten’s death. The first time he is reliably mentioned is in the the Chronicle of Greater Poland, which gives some clue as to why the evidence is so scanty:
\epigraph{"[Boleslaus] meanwhile, because of his severity and the horrors of his crimes, … though he was awarded the crown royal, shall not be placed among the Polish kings and princes.}{Wielkopolska Chronicle}
It seems likely that Boleslaus was, if not the leader, at least instrumental in the Pagan Reaction, a mutiny of the nobility in the 1030s in an attempt to ward off Christianity. In an effort to quell paganism in the country, it seems that his brother, successor (and one-time monk) Casimir I and his descendants came up with an efficient solution to hiding the skeletons in the closet of the House of Piast – damnatio memoriæ.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a complete (but minimal) example showing the issue? It should start with `\documentclass` and finish with `\end{document}` so that it can be run on other people's machines.

Comment: Apologies, I meant \epigraph in the title. I've now added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not at the end of `\epigraph`, but at the beginning!

The missing blank line before `\epigraph` makes everything go awry, causing very low level errors due to the ignored `\prevdepth` that's out of place if TeX is not in vertical mode as it should be.

The command definition should start with `\par`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\epigraph}{\par}{}{}

\begin{document}

No sources from the time explicitly indicate his existence
\epigraph{"[Boleslaus] meanwhile, because of his severity}{Wielkopolska Chronicle}
It seems likely that Boleslaus was, if not the leader, at least instrumental

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I'd find it clearer to *use* blank lines.

```
No sources from the time explicitly indicate his existence

\epigraph{"[Boleslaus] meanwhile, because of his severity}{Wielkopolska Chronicle}

It seems likely that Boleslaus was, if not the leader, at least instrumental
```

I left it, but for double quotes the character `"` should never be used.

Comment: thank you so much!